# assign arraylist to dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am creating `div` dynamically ,and iterating lists inside `ArrayList` and I want assign these list to each div index-wise, means `div0` has `list1`, `div2` has `list2` so on.
example:    example:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
s=doc.createlement(div);    
s=doc.createlement(div);
s.innerHTML=<c:foreach>iteraing list</c:foreach>    
s.innerHTML=<c:foreach>iteraing list</c:foreach>
```

where all list comes on single div..so help me to assign it on individual div   where all list comes on single div..so help me to assign it on individual div

```
s.innerHTML="<c:forEach var="i" items="${c}"><c:forEach var="a" items="${i}"> 
s.innerHTML="<c:forEach var="i" items="${c}"><c:forEach var="a" items="${i}">
<li><c:out value="${a}"/></li></c:forEach></c:forEach>";    
<li><c:out value="${a}"/>    
</li></c:forEach></c:forEach>";
}
```

so how could i assign list ti individual div?is it possible to use index if dynamically created div(e.g. in this exam s[i].innerHTML="";)??

Answer (score 0):

Give each one of your divs a unique id, for example div0, div1, div2 and then use jQuery to iterate through your array list and set the HTML for each div.

```
for(i=0; i<ArrayList.length; i++)
{
   $('div'+i).html(ArrayList[i]);
}
```